# Update column using conditional statement python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to update col4 if there is no NaN in the rows OR the values in col1 + col2 OR col3 is equals to 0.

If col1 & col2 and col3, all the columns having values '0' we need to update col4 with Error message.

**Input Data:**

```
col1    col2     col3    col4
130     550       0
0        0       125    
220      0        0
0        0        0
NaN     NaN      NaN
725     725       0
0       0        550
```

**Expected Output:**

```
col1    col2     col3    col4
130     550       0      Success
0        0       125     Success
220      0        0      Success
0        0        0      UnSupported Values
NaN     NaN      NaN     Unsupported values
725     725       0      Success
0       0        550     Success
```

**Code i have been using**

```
df['col4']=np.where(df[['col1', 'col2','col3']].isna().all(axis=1) | df[['col1', 'col2','col3']]<=0, 'Unsupported values' , 'Success')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `(df[['col1', 'col2','col3']]<=0).all(1)` to get True if all of the specified column values are <=0.

Also, Always use parenthesis when you use operators (`|`, `&`, `and`, `or` etc)

```
df['col4'] = np.where((df[['col1', 'col2','col3']].isna().all(axis=1)) | ((df[['col1', 'col2','col3']]<=0).all(1)), 'Unsupported values' , 'Success')
```

Comment: Gives Error Where it finds any float value For Eg:  125.98, TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Convert column type from string to float using `df[column_name].astype(float)`